# $().toggleClass(); not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, toggleclass

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Shmoyojoe/w8yuZ/1/) is the Fiddle. I am trying to make my own checkbox by using a `<div>`, and applying colors with `$().css()`. When you click the `div`, I am trying to use `$().toggleClass()` in a click function to change the background-color to `#96f226`

jQuery:

```
$('div').mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).css('background','#656565');
});
$('div').mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).css('background','#4a4a4a');
});
$('div').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

HTML:

```
<div></div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    background: #4a4a4a;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.active {
    background: #96f226
}
```

Comment: is this in a dom ready state?

Comment: what do you mean by that? do you mean if it's in `$(document).ready()`?

Comment: @JJP Is your JavaScript code exactly as you stated, or is it wrapped in `$(document).ready(function() { /* your code here */ });`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With that `.css` call for 'background' property, you change the corresponding *inline* style of an element, specified as its attribute. In other words, your `mouseenter` handler turns `<div>` into `<div style="background: ##656565">`. `mouseleave` works the similar way, it's just the value of `style` attribute that is different.

The problem is that style rule set in that way - within `style` attribute - has the highest [**specificity**](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#specificity) than the one applied as a result of a class-match rule (or any combination of selectors) given in the CSS ruleset.

That's why you don't see any changes when class `active` is added to the element (and it's easy to check that the class IS added indeed; it's just its rule that's not accounted).

That problem is quite easy to fix if you remove all fiddling with inline styles altogether, and use another class - for `mouseenter` handler to set, and `mouseleave` to remove.

But actually, you don't even need that: the events you're trying to process are already handled by browser, in quite a good way. It's to easy to leverage: just set up the style rules for [**:hover**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover) pseudo-class, like this:

```
div:hover {
    background: #656565
}
div.active, div.active:hover {
    background: #96f226
}
```

And here's a [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/LppXL/) to play with.

Comment: This is the best, most non-intrusive way for sure!

Answer (score 1):

It is because the priority order of a `class` is lower than the `style` attribute.

Comment: @JJP: http://www.amazon.com/Logitech-920-002478-Keyboard-K120/dp/B003ELVLKU/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1378254793&sr=8-1&keywords=keyboard - get a new keyboard, with the current one you have a problems with a `?` key

Comment: oh...kinda built into my laptop

Answer (score 0):

When you set the CSS property directly on the element, this takes priority over your toggled class. To make it work you have to add another class.

```
.enter {
   background: #656565;
}
```

And then your JS would be like this:

```
$('div').mouseenter(function(){
   $(this).addClass("enter");
});
$('div').mouseleave(function(){
   $(this).removeClass("enter");
});
$('div').click(function(){
   $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

See this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/w8yuZ/5/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(function(){

    $('div').mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).css('background','#656565');
    });

    $('div').mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).css('background','#4a4a4a');
    });

    $('div').click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
    });

});
```

Answer (score -3):

this will help you:

```
.active {
    background: #96f226 !important;
}
```

Comment: This is not recommended.  `!important` should be used sparingly and only in cases where it has a specific utility.

Comment: @JJP I highly recommend [this answer instead](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18603599/437226).  This is not the best solution and accepting it may be misleading to future people with the same problem.  Stack Overflow is not just about what works--it's about being useful to future users; that is why it is getting -1's.

Comment: @JJP You'll understand that when coming here again, asking for help with mysterious style that just doesn't want to go away - somehow.

Comment: its another solution for the problem? maybe someone will have to set inline style for some reason. this would be helpfull then. i understand that is not the the best answer, but -1 for that?
but ok.

Comment: @reyaner: Don't take it personally. The point of SO is to make sure the best answer bubbles to the top. That requires us to downvote answers that don't follow best practices